# Definition of Riemann integral with fixed tags and arbitrary partitions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

**Definition:**
$f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with integral $I$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0$ such that for every partition $P=\{a=x_0 <x_1< \ldots < x_n =b\}$ of $[a,b]$ with $||P||< \delta$ and for **every** tag $t_i  \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$, $\forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$, we have, $$\left|\sum\limits_{i =1}^n f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i-1}) -I \right|<\epsilon$$

Here, along with partitions, tags chosen from each subinterval also need to be arbitrary. But on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Similar_concepts), it says,

> One popular restriction is the use of "left-hand" and "right-hand"
> Riemann sums. In a left-hand Riemann sum, $t_i = x_i$ for all $i$, and in a
> right-hand Riemann sum, $t_i = x_{i + 1}$ for all $i$. Alone this restriction
> does not impose a problem: we can refine any partition in a way that
> makes it a left-hand or right-hand sum by subdividing it at each $t_i$.

So my question is, does choosing fixed tags $t_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ , not necessarily endpoints but just any one point in the subintervals enough, given that the partitions are allowed to be arbitrary?

**More formally:** If $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that for every partition $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b\}$ of $[a,b]$ and for a **fixed** $t_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i], \forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$, we have, $$\left|\sum\limits_{i =1}^n f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i-1}) -I \right|<\epsilon$$ then is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with integral $I$?

---

I'd normally think of going from Riemann sums to Darboux sums but since the tags are not arbitrary, I'm not sure how I'd relate values of function on each subinterval with supremum/infimum of that subinterval. Thoughts?

Comment: This [7 November 2007 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/UALfM26dlQg/m/8R8XAi_q9rgJ) might include results related to what you're asking about, but I don't have time now to dig back into this topic. See also the mathoverflow question [Cauchy's left endpoint integral (1823)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/127615/15780).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Woah that sent me down one of the most rabbitiest, holiest, rabbit hole and yet I wasn't able to find anything haha. I'll try again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a fixed tag, I'm assuming you mean that for each interval of a partition, you get to pick a specific point of your choice.

If a function satisfies your fixed tag definition then it may still not be Riemann integrable. The function $f : [0, 1]\to [0, 1]$ taking value 1 on rationals and 0 on irrationals is not Riemann integrable. However, it will satisfy your definition and have integral of 1 if your fixed tag is always rational and integral of 0 if your fixed tag is always irrational.

Comment: Thank you and well that's a bummer. Choices like $t_i =\frac{x_i-x_{i-1}}{4}$ would work because I suppose you can vary $x_i$s (by choosing a suitable partition) so that $t_i$ takes both rationals and irrationals. But doesn't work if you just fix any $t_i$.